# Partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$ are equal at $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If $f(x, y) = f(y, x)$ for all $(x, y) ∈ \mathbb R^2$.

Show that $\frac{∂f}{∂x}(a, b) = \frac{∂f}{∂y}(b, a)$

For all $(a,b) ∈ \mathbb R^2$.

So far I think that I need to put  $f(x, y) = gf(x, y)$ But I am not sure where to go from here, Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Change of variables :  $\begin{cases}
s=x+y \\
t=x-y\\
\end{cases} \quad \to \quad$
$f(x,y) = g(s,t) $

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial s} - \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}$$

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)_{(a,b)} =  \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\right)_{(a+b\:,\:a-b)} +\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(a+b\:,\:a-b)} $

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)_{(b,a)} =  \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\right)_{(a+b\:,\:b-a)} -\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(a+b\:,\:b-a)} $

This is true any $a,b$ , so, it is true in case of $a=b$ :

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)_{(a,a)} =  \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} +\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} $

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)_{(a,a)} =  \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} -\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} $

Now, with the condition :

$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)_{(a,b)} = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right)_{(b,a)}$$

$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)_{(a,a)} =  \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} +\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} =
  \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial s}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} -\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} $

$$\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} = -\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}\right)_{(2a\:,\:0)} \quad \implies \quad =0$$

Hense $g$ is not function of $t$. It is function of $s=a+b$ only. That is : $g(s,t)=G(s)$ where $G$ is any derivable function.

$f(a,b)=G(a+b)$ . Thus, the general solution is :
$$f(x,y)=G(x+y) \quad \text{any derivable function } G.$$